# SATA in Samsung Exynos

Tags: hardware, smartphone, cpu-architecture, dma, sata

Please take a look at the picture below.
[image]

You can see that Samsung integrates SATA 3 into the Exynos 5 Dual. So does that mean that smartphones which use Exynos 5 will be able to connect to hard drives or optical drives by using SATA interface ? Do I misunderstand anything ?

And also, does DMA in the figure ("32x DMA") refer to "Direct Memory Accessing" ?

Answer (score 0):

Exynos is a general SoC (System on chip solution) that is mainly used in Samsung's high-end smartphones, but it is still not exclusively design for smartphones. Like most SoC platforms, it packs a whole lot of peripherals and features, most of which are not likely used in one application, but are there to be used in another application if needed (like a NAS device - network attached storage). This is the general nature of SoC chips.